# Native interface for searching and finding

Tags: c#, wpf, search, full-text-search, find

Does there any Interface exist that's for searching something like `ISearch` or `IFind` ?

I just found some selfmade interfaces but i'm pretty sure there must be a default interface for this. Do i really must write my own interface?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that such a thing does not exist.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn so you have also searched for such a interface?

Comment: Actually, no. I say I'm sure because it is not something that can be generalized.

Comment: mhh i thought it could be some generic interface or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

- [Windows Search Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There you will find *links* to the SDK download and code samples as well.

The Windows Search, of course, includes query-related interfaces: [Querying Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: not really what i was looking for  because i doesn't want to download anything. I just want to use native provided `Dll's`